# how to add data using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularjs. I want to add data in database and to show in a table.There is one input name field and one image field.

my html is
*service.html*:

```
  <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="addservices" class="modal fade">
                <form role="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="submitCuisine(myForm.$valid)" novalidate>
      <div class="modal-dialog" >
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">

                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Add Service</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.cat.$invalid && myForm.cat.$touched }">

                  Category <input type="text" name= "cat" id= "cat" ng-model="dataform.cat"  autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix">
              </div><br>
             <div class="modal-body" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.name.$invalid && myForm.name.$touched }"> Service Name<input type="text" name= "name" id= "name" ng-model="dataform.name"  autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix"></div>
                 <div class="modal-body" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.desc.$invalid && myForm.desc.$touched }"> Description<input type="text" name= "desc" id= "desc" ng-model="dataform.desc" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix"></div>
                <div class="modal-body" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.cost.$invalid && myForm.cost.$touched }">  Cost($)<input type="text" name= "cost" id= "cost"  ng-model="dataform.cost" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix"></div>
                <div class="modal-body" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.servicetime.$invalid && myForm.servicetime.$touched }">  Time(min)<input type="text" name= "servicetime" id= "servicetime" ng-model="dataform.servicetime"  autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix"></div>
                <div class="modal-body">  Image  <input type="file"  file-input="files" name="file"/>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
                </form>
  </div>
```

addserviceController.js

```
 app.controller('addserviceController', function ($scope,$http,$cookieStore) {


       $scope.submitCuisine=function(isvalid){
        if(isvalid){
            var fd=new FormData();
            angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
                fd.append('file',file);
            });

            fd.append('formdata',JSON.stringify($scope.dataform));

            $http.post('admin/managecuisineAdd',fd,{
                access_token : $cookieStore.get('obj').accesstoken,
                transformRequest:angular.identity,
                headers:{'Content-type':undefined}
            }).success(function(data){
                $scope.status=data;
                $scope.itemlist.push(data)
                $scope.message="New Dish Added Successfully"
            });
        }   
    } 



});
```

app.js

```
(function(window){

var app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute','ngCookies','ui.bootstrap']);




app.directive("fileInput",['$parse',function($parse){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
            ele.bind('change',function(){
                $parse(attrs.fileInput).
                assign(scope,ele[0].files)
                scope.$apply()
            });
        }
    }
}]);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            controller: 'loginController',
               templateUrl: 'app/views/loginuser.html'
        })

            .when('/logout', {
                title: 'Logout',
                templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .when('/dashboard', {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/dynamic_table.html',
                controller: 'dashboard'
            })
            .when('/verified_artists', {
                title: 'Verified Artists',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/verified_artists.html',
                controller: 'artistController'
            })
            .when('/new_artists', {
                title: 'New Request Artists',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/new_artists.html',
                controller: 'verifyartistController'
            })
            .when('/services', {
                title: 'Services',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/services.html',
                controller: 'serviceController'
            })
           .when('/addservices', {
                title: 'Services',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/services.html',
                controller: 'addserviceController'
            })

  }]);
   window.app = app;

}(window));
```

I have made one controller `addserviceController.js`. I want that when I click on Submit button, it will go to controller where I will hit an api but I don't know how to send data of name and image field and also help me what I will write in controller.Please tell me how to get data of input field and pass to the controller where it will hit an api so that data will save to database.

Comment: do you know how the normal databinding works? i.e. with the model and scope? `<input ng-model="variable" />` and `$scope.variable` in your controller.

Comment: If you are wondering why not any answer yet, it's because your question is too complicated, with too few details. You should ask something like "How to call controller method with parameters from ng-click function?"...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the $http service to make AJAX requests or interact with a RESTful Service.
More detail how to use $http service is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code what i did in my project to upload image and data:- 
HTML PAGE :-
<form role="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="submitCuisine(myForm.$valid)" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.name.$invalid && myForm.name.$touched }">
               <label for="name">Name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name"
                  placeholder="Name of cuisine" ng-model="dataform.name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.description.$invalid && myForm.description.$touched }">
               <label for="description">Description</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" 
                  placeholder="Description for cuisine" ng-model="dataform.description" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.category.$invalid && myForm.category.$touched }">
               <label for="description">Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="dataform.category" id="category" name="category" required>
                   <option>Veg</option>
                   <option>Non-veg</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.subcategory.$invalid && myForm.subcategory.$touched }">
               <label for="description">Sub-Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="dataform.subcategory" id="subcategory" name="subcategory" required>
                   <option>Main Course</option>
                   <option>Staters</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.price.$invalid && myForm.price.$touched }">
               <label for="description">Price</label>
               <span class="fa fa-dollar"></span>
               <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" 
                  placeholder="Price" ng-model="dataform.price" required>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="description">Image</label> 
               <input type="file"  file-input="files" name="file"/>
            </div>  
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"> Submit</button>
        </form>



Controller:-
$scope.submitCuisine=function(isvalid){
    if(isvalid){
        var fd=new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
            fd.append('file',file);
        });

        fd.append('formdata',JSON.stringify($scope.dataform));

        $http.post('admin/managecuisineAdd',fd,{
            transformRequest:angular.identity,
            headers:{'Content-type':undefined}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.status=data;
            $scope.itemlist.push(data)
            $scope.message="New Dish Added Successfully"
        });
    }   
}

Directive :-
myApp.directive("fileInput",['$parse',function($parse){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
            ele.bind('change',function(){
                $parse(attrs.fileInput).
                assign(scope,ele[0].files)
                scope.$apply()
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I follow your code then also it is not working please see my html and controller above i just edited my code and tell me where i am doing mistake

Comment: Change "'admin/managecuisineAdd'" to your server api and if you want to see the angular end is working properly or not just use console.log(fd) it will show you data and image in encrypted form.

Comment: Ya i changed to my url i.e.,http://54.173.65.120:2500/add_new_service and console.log(fd) but nothing shows and no error also..

Comment: when i console, it shows error
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: can you please tell me how to solve this TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Here is th link of plunker "http://plnkr.co/edit/yPNA0ij3Dn37tsI9w7Z2?p=preview" check the post header in firebug you will find that it is showing image in encrypted form and data in the end of it.

Comment: ya i have also done like that then why it shows error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: REMOVE "           $scope.status=data;
            $scope.itemlist.push(data)"
because it may be possible server is responding with error.

Comment: then it shows message only FormData {append: function} and nothing else and data is also not added

Comment: I guess now atleast everthing is fine by Angular end you must have to configure your server end for response.
Check your request form networks in firefox you will see that data is sending properly but response is not properly provided by server side.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I thought you could use angular-ui and the modal from bootstrap there.

This example is the one from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ modificated for your needs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      < div class = "modal-header" > < h3 class = "modal-title" > I 'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Your Variable
        <input ng-model="variable" />
        </label>
            <p>Variable: <b>{{ variable }}</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <div ng-show="variable">Variable input from a modal: {{ variable }}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and your javascript:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.variable = "initial value";

  $scope.open = function(size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
         variable: function() {
           return $scope.variable;
         }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(variable) {

      //your special processing here
      $scope.variable = variable.toUpperCase();
    }, function() {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, variable) {

  $scope.variable = variable;

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.variable);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

I'm doing the same here and everything is working fine.

working demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yXEGPXejWdlLrniDGQs5?p=preview